# Tooltip.followPointer does not work in highcharts 3

Tags: touch, highcharts, tooltip

with HighCharts 3, on touch devices, we can't anymore make the tooltip follow the touch.

But I've seen about the new option `Tooltip`.`followPointer`.

The aim is to *get back* the behaviour of Highcharts 2 by disabling panning and making the tooltip follow the touch, on touch devices like :

```
    chart: {
        panning: false,
    },

    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: true,
        followPointer: true
    },
```

But it does not seem to work..

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/jpFgq/1/

Comment: This is known bug, but is reported to our devs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be fixed by now, with the creation of a new parameter : '[followTouchMove](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.spline.tooltip.followTouchMove)'

```
 chart: {
        panning: false,
    },

    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: true,
        followPointer: true,
        followTouchMove: true
    },
```

Here's the [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpFgq/6/). Works fine on the ipad.